# SSH into remote server using Public-private keys

Tags: linux, ssh, mac

I have recently setup ssh on two linux machines (lets call them server-a, client-b). I have generated two ssh auth files on client-b machine using ssh key gen and can see both public and private files in .ssh dir. I have named them 'example' and 'example.pub'.

Then I have added example.pub to sever-a's auth file. 
When I try to ssh into server-a it still requests a password authentication where as I want a password less login (private key on client-b is setup without password).

When I try to ssh with '-v' .. get  the following output:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/abc/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

Please help.

Comment: can you be a little more precise about how you put the key on the server?  You said "auth file".  Could you list the exact name and location you put the key?

Comment: If you really named your keyfiles example and example.pub, ssh nor sshd will know where to find them. Just use the standard filenames suggested by ssh-keygen and copy the public key to remote server as .ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 1):

You may also  use 'ssh-copy-id' to upload the public key to the server.

Syntax is:

```
ssh-copy-id [-i [identity_file]] [user@]machine
```

Respond to Trevor's questions above if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Pubkey auth can be kind of annoying sometimes.  The default location for authorized key files is ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and the key has to be in single-line format (everything on one line, and for me, if it was ever in more than 1 line format, you could pretty much abandon all hope at that point of getting it to work).

Also, stupid idea, but you might make sure that the location .ssh/authorized_keys is set as a primary value for the default location for public keys.

Also might check the log files on the server to see if there's any good info.